# FreeNAS/ZFS with both RAID-Z and Mirror?

Tags: freebsd, nas, zfs

I'm considering switching to FreeNAS at the same time I'm acquiring some new disks for my home server.  The end configuration will have a 1.5TB drive (currently the largest disk in the set) and two 3TB drives.

The "obvious" way to structure this (to me) would be to create partitions on the 3TB drives equal in size to the full 1.5TB drive, then RAID-Z those partitions together for 3TB of redundant storage.  The remainder of the 3TB drives could be mirrored together for another 1.5TB of redundant storage.  This seems like it gives me no wasted space, and a full 4.5TB of redundant storage to work with.

The problem is that I can't find anything that would let me treat these two segments as a single pool.  I don't really care if any given data is written to parity vs. mirrored space, so long as it's all resilient to a single disk failure.

Am I stuck with two virtual spaces and allocating data between them, or is there a ZFS option I'm not finding that would let me pool the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should be able to build a pool with two vdevs -- one with RAID-Z with 3 partitions and another a mirror with 2 partitions.

Something like this should work:

> zpool create tank raidz da0p0 da1p0 da2p0 mirror da0p1 da1p1

That said, you **don't** want to do that for performance reasons. Reads and writes will be distributed across **all** vdevs, and, as the result, across **all* your partitions for every chunk of data ZFS needs to write out. In the end your 3GB hard drives will have to do two seeks access data on different partitions *each* time ZFS writes out each transaction group. Once data is written, similar seeks will be needed to read data that's not in ARC yet. At 10-20ms per seek performance will be rather terrible.